# Android Studio Kotlin synthetic view variable refresh/regenerate

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

After changing the view's type, there are build errors that the variable is still an old type. How can I force Android Studio to refresh/regenerate the variables with current types?

For example,

```
<ImageView   id="@+id/myView>
and in code
myView.setImage = someImage
```

Now, I change the type in the XML editor,

```
<TextView   id="@+id/myView>
```

Now this line causes an error like myView has no "setImage" method, because it still thinks myView is a TextView.

```
myView.setText(some text);
```

Comment: Had the same issue, but with values of the static arrayList... Tried "Invalidate and Restart" under File menu already? Also try to rename viewID, compile, rename back and compile.

Comment: I have tried invalidation, but it did not solve the problem. So I went back to the old way, findviewbyid.